# How to remove duplicate in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to show bandwidth usage per month,
there are 2 users who both logged in on June
here is my code :

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row):

            $date = $row['acctstarttime'];
            $d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date);

             $monthNum  = $d["month"];
             $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
             $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');                
                        ?>

                <td><?php echo $monthName;?></td>
                </tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

The Output is :
 - June
                - June
                - July

The output I need : 
- June
- July

I tried to change my query to :

```
Function showData() 
    { 

    $this->db->distinct('radacct.acctstarttime'); 
    $this->db->from('radacct');
    $this->db->where('radacct.acctstarttime','y-06-d-h');
    $query = $this->db->get();


    If ($query->num_rows()>0) 
    { 
      Return $query->result(); 
    } 
    Else 
    { 
     Return array(); 
    } 
 }
```

But it changes nothing (Is my query wrong ?)

I also tried : `foreach (array_unique($data) as $row)`

But it removes the July

the output of `<?php print_r($row['acctstarttime'])?>`
is : 2017-06-08 04:12:00    2017-06-08 04:12:00     2017-07-12 05:00:00

Comment: Please show an example of the array you want to process

Comment: Looks like `$this->db->distinct('radacct.acctstarttime'); ` is using all the components of the time, whereas you just want the month?

Comment: yes mr. nigel, one of those data is "2017-06-08 04:12:00" i just want the "Y-06-D-H" the "06" part

Comment: Excuse me mr. Riggs did u mean this one ? 'foreach ($data as $row)'

Comment: No add the output from a `print_r($the_array)` to your question

Comment: umm something like this ?  `<?php print_r($row['acctstarttime'])?> `<br/>
the output is 2017-06-08 04:12:00 2017-06-08 04:12:00 2017-07-12 05:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
    <?php 
    $month = [];
    foreach ($data as $row):
        if(!in_array($d["month"], $month)) {
            $month[] = $d['month'];
            $date = $row['acctstarttime'];
            $d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date);

            $monthNum  = $d["month"];
            $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
            $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');                
            ?>

            <td><?php echo $monthName;?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php 
        }
     endforeach;
  ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    $month = array(); 
    foreach ($data as $row):
       $date = $row['acctstarttime'];
       $d = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d", $date);
       $monthNum  = $d["month"];
       $dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
       $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');  
       if(!in_array($monthName, $month)) {
            $month[] = $monthName;
            echo $monthName;
       }
     endforeach;
```

Comment: Tried, and modified it,
But the output is still :
-June
-June
-July

Comment: Uhm... is not possibile if that was your code, can you please provide an example and publish for example to phpfiddle?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort sir, here is the link : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ykcq-3d16

Comment: update the answer, try now please @IhsanMabroChickenz

Comment: It Works !! :D Thanks a alot sir

Comment: Glad to help you!